# Julia: @time a set of functions

Tags: time, julia

I have a `script.jl` which looks more or less like this:

```
...

function main()
    a::... = function1()
    b::... = function2(...)
    c::... = function3(...)
    A::... = function4(...)
    B::... = function5(...)
    C::... = function6(...)
end

main()
```

I cannot `@time main()` because functions 1-3 are input functions and therefore their execution times depend on how fast or slow the user is.
Is there a way to time only function 4-6?
I don't know, something like this:

```
...

function main()
    a::... = function1()
    b::... = function2(...)
    c::... = function3(...)
    @time(
    A::... = function4(...)
    B::... = function5(...)
    C::... = function6(...)
    )
end

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get the time elapsed is with the functions tic() and toc():

Example:

```
function main()
    a::... = function1()
    b::... = function2(...)
    c::... = function3(...)
    tic()
    A::... = function4(...)
    B::... = function5(...)
    C::... = function6(...)
    toc()
end
```

---

*Update*: tic and toc functions were deprecated in Julia version >= 1.0 and do not work anymore. You can use [@time](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/base/#Base.@time) as described at @SalchiPapa's answer or use the package [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl), which have a lot of great functions for performance tracking of Julia code.

Answer (score 12):

**Note:** I guess this is just an example but the syntax `C::...` is not valid Julia syntax, it's better if you provide simple but functional examples.

You can prepend each expression that you are interested in timing with a `@time` macro annotation if you want independent timings:

```rb
function main()
    a = function1()
    b = function2(...)
    c = function3(...)
    @time A = function4(...)
    @time B = function5(...)
    @time C = function6(...)
end

main()
```

or:

```rb
function main()
    a = function1()
    b = function2(...)
    c = function3(...)
    @time begin
        A = function4(...)
        B = function5(...)
        C = function6(...)
    end
end

main()
```

This is similar to @Gomiero answer, just that in order to time several functions with the `@time` macro you need to introduce a new block and stuff everything in there.

Also checkout the still unregistered package`Benchmarks`, ie:

```rb
julia> Pkg.add("https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/Benchmarks.jl.git")

julia> using Benchmarks

julia> function test()
           x = 0
           for i in 1:1000_000_000
               x += 1
           end
           return x
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time test()    # JIT warmup!
  0.003669 seconds (1.71 k allocations: 90.799 KB)
1000000000

julia> @time test()
  0.000002 seconds (5 allocations: 176 bytes)
1000000000

julia> @benchmark test()
================ Benchmark Results ========================
     Time per evaluation: 6.03 ns [5.92 ns, 6.13 ns]
Proportion of time in GC: 0.00% [0.00%, 0.00%]
        Memory allocated: 0.00 bytes
   Number of allocations: 0 allocations
       Number of samples: 6301
   Number of evaluations: 811601
         R² of OLS model: 0.951
 Time spent benchmarking: 2.96 s
```

If you want to time several expressions use the `begin` block approach.

Comment: What about saving result to a variable (Only the runtime result)?

Comment: @Royi then you would just do `x = @time foo()`, or `x = @btime foo()`, `@btime` comes from `BenchmarkTools` also.

Comment: Actually `@btime` will put the function result into the variable. If someone, A I wrote above, wants the run time set to a variable one should use `runTime = @elapsed foo();` or `runTime = @belapsed foo();` given `BenchmarkTools.jl`.

Comment: @Royi oh got it, I did not understand you, glad you found how to do it.